# How to get data from an object and data from its children which has the same arrangement and so on using a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have a family tree data that has an arrangement like an org chart.

this is the arrangement of the data

```
var datasource = {
    name: "'Adnan",
    sex: "Male",
    title: "",
    generation: 1,
    children: [
        {
            name: "Ma'ad",
            sex: "Male",
            title: "",
            generation: 2,
            father: "'Adnan",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Nizar",
                    sex: "Male",
                    title: "",
                    generation: 3,
                    father: "Ma'ad",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "Mudhar",
                            sex: "Male",
                            title: "",
                            generation: 4,
                            father: "Nizar",
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "Qays 'Aylan",
                                    sex: "Male",
                                    title: "",
                                    generation: 5,
                                    father: "Mudhar",
                                    children: [
                                        {
                                            name: "Khashafah",
                                            sex: "Male",
                                            title: "",
                                            generation: 6,
                                            father: "Qays 'Aylan",
                                            children: [
                                                {
                                                    // And so on...
                                                },
                                            ]
                                        },
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Ilyas",
                                    sex: "Male",
                                    title: "",
                                    generation: 5,
                                    father: "Mudhar",
                                    children: [
                                        {
                                            name: "Mudrikah",
                                            sex: "Male",
                                            title: "",
                                            generation: 6,
                                            father: "Ilyas",
                                            children: [
                                                {
                                                    // And so on...
                                                },
                                            ]
                                        },
                                    ]
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
};
```

I want to take all the names from that data and then put them in one object.

And this is the code that I've been working with

```
function extractData (data) {

    var source = data;
    
    // Print out Adnan's name
    console.log(source.name);
    // Open data Adnan child
    var a = source.children;
    // Find out how much information on Adnan's children data
    for (var key in a) {
        // Extract Maad data from Adnan
        var b = a[key];
        // Print out Maad's name through Adnan
        console.log(b.name);
        // Open data Maad child through Adnan
        var c = b.children;
        // Find out how much information on Maad's children data
        for (var key in c) {
            // Extract Nizar data from Maad
            var d = c[key];
            // Print out Nizar's name through Maad
            console.log(d.name);
            // Open data Nizar child through Maad
            var e = d.children;
            // Find out how much information on Nizar's children data
            for (var key in e) {
                // Extract Mudhar data from Nizar
                var f = e[key];
                // Print out Mudhar's name through Nizar
                console.log(f.name);
                // Open data Mudhar child through Nizar
                var g = f.children;
                // Find out how much information on Mudhar's children data
                for (var key in g) {
                    // Extract Qays and Ilyas data from Mudhar
                    var h = g[key];
                    // Print out Qays's name and Ilyas's name through Mudhar
                    console.log(h.name);
                    // Open data Qays child and Ilyas child through Mudhar
                    var i = h.children;
                    // Find out how much information on Qays's children and Ilyas's children datas
                    for (var key in i) {
                        // Extract Khashafah and Mudrikah data from Qays and Ilyas
                        var j = i[key];
                        // Print out Khashafah's name and Mudrikah's name through Qays and Ilyas
                        console.log(j.name);
                        // Open data Khashafah child and Mudrikah child through Qays and Ilyas
                        var k = j.children;

                        // And so on...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't want to use that method because if I add more data, I have to add some more code. It would be very tiring.

And also I have another family data and I want to be able to use the same function.

Instead, I want that code to be converted into a looping method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the person doesn't have any children, you can just return their name in an array (the base case).

If they do have children, you can return an array with their name and then use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to map over each child and call the `getNames` function recursively and flatten the results by one level. You can then spread them in an array.

```js
const dataSource = { name: "'Adnan", sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 1, children: [ { name: "Ma'ad", sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 2, father: "'Adnan", children: [ { name: 'Nizar', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 3, father: "Ma'ad", children: [ { name: 'Mudhar', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 4, father: 'Nizar', children: [ { name: "Qays 'Aylan", sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 5, father: 'Mudhar', children: [ { name: 'Khashafah', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 6, father: "Qays 'Aylan", children: [], }, ], }, { name: 'Ilyas', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 5, father: 'Mudhar', children: [ { name: 'Mudrikah', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 6, father: 'Ilyas', children: [], }, ], }, ], }, ], }, ], }, ],}

const getNames = (person) => {
  if (!person.children.length) {
    return [person.name]
  }

  return [
    person.name,
    ...person.children.flatMap(getNames)
  ]
}

const names = getNames(dataSource)
console.log(names)
```

As Nick mentioned in a comment, you can omit the base case since the `flatMap` call will return an empty array if the person doesn't have any children.

```js
const dataSource = { name: "'Adnan", sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 1, children: [ { name: "Ma'ad", sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 2, father: "'Adnan", children: [ { name: 'Nizar', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 3, father: "Ma'ad", children: [ { name: 'Mudhar', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 4, father: 'Nizar', children: [ { name: "Qays 'Aylan", sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 5, father: 'Mudhar', children: [ { name: 'Khashafah', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 6, father: "Qays 'Aylan", children: [], }, ], }, { name: 'Ilyas', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 5, father: 'Mudhar', children: [ { name: 'Mudrikah', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 6, father: 'Ilyas', children: [], }, ], }, ], }, ], }, ], }, ],}

const getNames = (person) => [
  person.name,
  ...person.children.flatMap(getNames)
]

const names = getNames(dataSource)
console.log(names)
```

And you can make it even terser by destructuring `name` and `children`. (Thanks to Nick for the tip).

```js
const dataSource = { name: "'Adnan", sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 1, children: [ { name: "Ma'ad", sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 2, father: "'Adnan", children: [ { name: 'Nizar', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 3, father: "Ma'ad", children: [ { name: 'Mudhar', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 4, father: 'Nizar', children: [ { name: "Qays 'Aylan", sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 5, father: 'Mudhar', children: [ { name: 'Khashafah', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 6, father: "Qays 'Aylan", children: [], }, ], }, { name: 'Ilyas', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 5, father: 'Mudhar', children: [ { name: 'Mudrikah', sex: 'Male', title: '', generation: 6, father: 'Ilyas', children: [], }, ], }, ], }, ], }, ], }, ],}

const getNames = ({ name, children = [] }) => [
  name,
  ...children.flatMap(getNames),
]

const names = getNames(dataSource)
console.log(names)
```

Comment: Creating fresh copies of array again and again could make the program slow for large datasets.

Comment: Nice, you could make this more consice if you used destructuring with defaults: `const getNames = ({name, children=[]}) => [name, ...children.flatMap(getNames)];`

Comment: @NickParsons That's super concise. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @NickParsons Just updated the answer with your solution. Thanks again :)

Comment: JFYI, The second snippet without destructuring will break if any of the object is not having any `children` prop. I see in your example when there are no children it's considered as `children: []` but the prop itself could be missing. So, it's better to use third snippet in order to avoid such problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### You can use Recursion.

If there are children then for every child call the recursive function and push the `name` into an array.

**NOTE:** For my solution to work properly, if a person doesn't have any children either remove the children property completely or make the children property have an empty array.

```js
var datasource={name:"'Adnan",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:1,children:[{name:"Ma'ad",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:2,father:"'Adnan",children:[{name:"Nizar",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:3,father:"Ma'ad",children:[{name:"Mudhar",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:4,father:"Nizar",children:[{name:"Qays 'Aylan",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:5,father:"Mudhar",children:[{name:"Khashafah",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:6,father:"Qays 'Aylan"}]},{name:"Ilyas",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:5,father:"Mudhar",children:[{name:"Mudrikah",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:6,father:"Ilyas"}]}]}]}]}]};

let temp = datasource;
const members = [datasource.name];

const getChildren = (childrenArr) => {
  if (!childrenArr) return;
  
  childrenArr.forEach(({name, children}) => {
    members.push(name);
    getChildren(children);
  })
}

getChildren(datasource.children)
console.log(members)
```

Comment: The code doesn't return all the family members - Ilyas and Mudrikah are missing.

Comment: Updated my code to use recursion @ArunKumarMohan

Comment: @FarhanPradanaTallei Please let me know if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee I have checked all the answers, and they all solved my problem well without any issues.

There are some errors in the code that Arun gave me because in my data there are so many people who don't have any children.

but after I tried it with the new code he submitted with the help of Nick, then the errors were gone and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need recursion here. In Javascript a method can call itself and hand in a parameter doing this:

```
  // store the names here
  const names = [];

  var datasource = { /* your structure */};

  function findNextName(data) {

         // store the name in the array
        if (data.name) {
            names.push(data.name);
        }

        // call the method again and hand in each child 
        if (data.children) {
            data.children.forEach( child =>
                findNextName(child);
            )
        }       
 }

// start
findNextName(datasource);

// result
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using recursion as shown below

```js
var datasource = {name:"'Adnan",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:1,children:[{name:"Ma'ad",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:2,father:"'Adnan",children:[{name:"Nizar",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:3,father:"Ma'ad",children:[{name:"Mudhar",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:4,father:"Nizar",children:[{name:"Qays 'Aylan",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:5,father:"Mudhar",children:[{name:"Khashafah",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:6,father:"Qays 'Aylan",},]},{name:"Ilyas",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:5,father:"Mudhar",children:[{name:"Mudrikah",sex:"Male",title:"",generation:6,father:"Ilyas"}]}]}]}]}]};

const getAllNames = (data, res) => {
  let names = res || [];
  //Add name to the result array
  names.push(data.name);
  //If the object is having at least one child, then loop through all objects and 
  //add the name to the result object by calling the function itself
  //We can use `if (data.children?.length > 0)` instead of `if ((data.children || []).length > 0)` but has some browser limitations as it's a new feature
  if ((data.children || []).length > 0) {
    data.children.forEach(obj => {
      getAllNames(obj, names);
    })
  }
  return names;
}

console.log(getAllNames(datasource));
```